# Checksum does not matching with message

Tags: java, serial-port, hl7

Message:

```
R:<ENQ> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>1H|\^&|||9163500014<CR><ETX>56<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>2P|1||42670070||Meir Anna||19740410|F<CR><ETX>48<CR><LF>
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>3O|1|||^^^HBsAg<CR><ETX>72<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>4R|1|^^^HBsAg|0.059||<CR><ETX>EE<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>5P|2||43681136||Mueller^Fritz||19940428|M<CR><ETX>3E<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>6O|1|||^^^HBsAg<CR><ETX>75<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>7R|1|^^^HBsAg|59.882||<CR><ETX>33<CR><LF> 
S:<ACK> 
R:<STX>0L|1|N<CR><ETX>03<CR><LF>
S:<ACK> 
R:<EOT>
```

Upon this message I am getting checksum for all segments correctly except 5P segment. When I generating checksum for this segment generated checksum does not matches with given checksum (3E) I am getting 7C.

For checksum:

> The checksum is encoded as two characters sent after the  or 
>       character. The checksum includes the first character after  (the 
>       frame number) up to and including  or . It is computed by adding
>       the binary values of the characters, keeping the least significant eight bits 
>       of the result.

I don't understand what is the problem? Is this message problem or any thing else? I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some context information. This way it is really difficult to answer.

Have you checked for German umlauts? Your 5P segment seems error prone with special characters: Mueller^Fritz